# How to get div which contain specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following situation:

```
<div id="content">
 <h4 class="page-header">Editing personal data</h4>
 <div class="alert alert-success" id="personal-data-changed" style="display: block;">
     Your personal data has been updated.
 </div>
```

I am trying to get div with text "Your personal data has been updated." using this:

```
 $('div:contains("Your personal data has been updated.")');
```

But I get all divs up. (Parent divs). Is possible to get only one div.

Edit:

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: why not use the id ? "personal-data-changed"

Comment: Because I am writting acceptance test in JS and I would like to have generic method to finding messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All parents divs contain this text too. Use id for your selector or add `only-child suffix`

```
$( "div ... :only-child" )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.last()` or `:last` to get the desired div, because all the parents also contains that text

```
$('div:contains("Your personal data has been updated.")').last()
```